# Hide apk when installing from Google Play

Tags: android

I am publishing an app on Google Play. When the user downloads the app, the apk file is stored  in external memory and people misuse the apk file.

How can I hide the apk at install time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't exactly *hide* the apk file from users. You *can* force it to be installed on the internal memory instead of external, but I don't think that's going to help you. To do that, just make sure you don't use the `installLocation` attribute in the manifest.

[From the docs:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html)

> If you do not declare this attribute, your application will be installed on the internal storage only and it cannot be moved to the external storage

Note that this does not mean your apk is "safe" either way. Any rooted user can still access the file no matter where it is. The only way to prevent people from accessing it is to not distribute it.

Answer (score 2):

Google's App Licensing is probably what you're after. Have a read here: http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html

Specifically,

> Note: The Google Play Licensing service is primarily intended for paid applications that wish to verify that the current user did in fact pay for the application on Google Play. However, any application (including free apps) may use the licensing service to initiate the download of an APK expansion file.

Answer (score 0):

Although you try to hide and apk there is lots of apps in android to extract apk from the app.